# opening csv with r+ and it is writing to the end of the file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to get the data from a .csv file, separate it into a list of tuples, do stuff with this, then save the changes back to the csv file. My issue is that instead of replacing the data I have it is adding the changes as new lines at the bottom of my file. I am trying to avoid reopening the file and using the csv module. The code below is me opening it, saving it as my list of tuples, and trying to save this back to the file, however it is instead appending the file.

```
items_data = open("test.csv", "r+")
my_list = items_data.read().strip().split('\n')
for line in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[line] = tuple(my_list[line].split(","))
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for a in range(0,4):
        if a==3:
            items_data.write(my_list[i][a] + "\n")
        else:
            items_data.write(my_list[i][a] + ",")
items_data.close()
```

Comment: It is usually better to write data to a new file then rename it if everything went ok. Otherwise if your program has a runtime error, the file could be messed up.

Answer (score 0):

'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing. Unless you specify the location by using f.seek(offset) the writing will be at the end. So instead of trying to figure out offset value for each line, it would just easier to read the whole file, and process each line, and write the whole thing back to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the file moves the "file pointer". Since you have read in all the lines, the file pointer is now pointing to the end of file. So further writes are happening at the end of the file.

To write from the beginning of the file, you need to reset the file pointer to the start of the file by doing before you start writing data back:

```
items_data.seek(0,0)
```

Your modified code should look like:

```
items_data = open("test.csv", "r+")
my_list = items_data.read().strip().split('\n')
for line in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[line] = tuple(my_list[line].split(","))

# rewind file pointer to the start of the file
items_data.seek(0,0)

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for a in range(0,4):
        if a==3:
            items_data.write(my_list[i][a] + "\n")
        else:
            items_data.write(my_list[i][a] + ",")
items_data.close()
```